# Will it throw an exception if it is null?

Tags: kotlin

I am pretty new Kotlin world and do not understand the following code snippet:

```
  @GET
  @Path("/env/{id}")
  fun read(@PathParam("id") id: EnvStageId): Uni<Environment> =
      createUni(repo.read(id)).map {
        it ?: throw WebApplicationException(Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
            .type(TEXT_PLAIN)
            .entity("Environment $id does not exist")
            .build())
      }
```

The question is, if `it` is null it will then throw an exception right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elvis operator `?:` is `not null or the continuation`.

Yes. If it is null then it will throw an exception.

The thing is, sometimes it is better to crash: if that operation is supposed to always return something from the local db, then if it fails you get an alert that there is something very bad going on, crashalytica for prod are standard this days.

Maybe the design is exceptions throwing exceptions on low level implementations. I do not think so, because that seems to be mixing network with repository, so I will doubt it. But on the other hand it seems to be so, because someone wrote an special exception for that, if it so, then the next architecture layer should catch those exceptions and handle them gracefully.